# How do I determine if a class action settlement offer is legitimate?

Tags: settlement, class-action

I recently received an email from [Halvorson](http://www.halvorsonsettlement.com/submit-a-claim-log-in.html) regarding the lawsuit with Talentbin that I'm entitled to a settlement. I have to submit a claim or if I want to exclude myself I also have to write a letter to them. However, I don't know if this is a scam or not. A quick Google and I found this http://www.classactionrebates.com/settlements/talentbin/

I don't know anything about the lawsuit.

They also mentioned this in the email.

> If you don’t exclude yourself, you may object to the Settlement or to the request for fees and costs by Class Counsel.

The reason I'm concerned is because even I want to get the settlement or exclude I have to submit my personal identification which I don't want to do.

How do I make sure that this is legit and not a scam?

Comment: It includes a court case number which you could look up on the court's online records system (for some courts there is a fee for this).

Comment: The court should be identified in the notice and finding its phone number on google should be easy. Call the clerk of that court to see if a real class action settlement notice was issued as claim.

Comment: I looked at the long claim version and it says "Note: Do not call or write the Court or the Court Clerk’s office for more information." http://www.halvorsonsettlement.com/pdf/Notice.pdf

And I couldn't find any information about the court.

Comment: I too received this e-mail and was suspicious because it's hard for me to imagine being a member of this class. That said, it appears to be legitimate. In addition to the steps outlined above by M. Morebucks, I read the long-form notice and called the toll-free number listed in the e-mail. Both appear to be exactly what I'd expect (having worked on several class-action lawsuits and be a party in several more).

Comment: I got notification on this today, and while I agree it all looks legit, I am somewhat concerned that this was my first notice and that _Exclusions must be submitted or postmarked no later than April 10, 2017._ I will ignore it (as on top of it I am moving back to Europe in a few weeks), but it didn't make sense to me that I was notified so late in the game, without a real option to exclude myself from it.

Comment: Definitely legitimate. I just received my settlement check in the mail today!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You rightly went to http://www.classactionrebates.com/settlements/talentbin/ which is a reliable source. I would say it was a safe site.

A quick search found this court document: https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar_case?case=5778378514805192456&q=Halvorson+v.+TalentBin,+Inc.&hl=en&as_sdt=2006&as_vis=1

which proves the existence of the case.

I would say everything is legitimate

Comment: The Google Scholar link included is now a 404

Comment: More info here: 
https://www.courthousenews.com/class-of-users-irked-by-talentbin-dossiers/

Comment: @tkdave that's a 2015 document. Just got the email too. Still debating if it's legit...

Comment: 2015 is when the case was filed. This docket timeline confirms the 6/9/17 and 7/14/17 deadlines. Just sharing what I found... https://www.courtlistener.com/docket/4182357/halvorson-v-talentbin-inc/

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston The Google Scholar link is working for me ...

Comment: went to topclassactions.com (noting here for future reference)

Answer (score 8):

I received an email too. I'm pretty sure it's legit. Here is the process I went through:

- I carefully read the email looking for grammar/spelling mistakes
- Was the language used simple or complex? Lawyers are always very complex and specific.
- Googled *Halvorson v. TalentBin, Inc.* to look for a reference to the actual case. That brought me here where Shazamo Morebucks has provided the reference.
- I did not click on any links until I reached this point.
- As I submitted my claim they didn't need any sensitive information like my social security number or birth date.